# Write React component and deploy it at runtime?

Tags: reactjs

I'm a bit new to React.

My company is starting to build a product than needs to be customized by *any client*.

Is it possible to create a component (let's call it ***plugin***) and deploy it into a folder in a production environment and that component being rendered without recompiling the entire app?

**e.g.**: I have a form and i need another form calling a client's API that renders some info and then pass that info to the main app form. That 2nd form should be this kind of plugin, due to the fact that it depends on the clients' APIs for the component to render a table, a chart, or whatever the component itself renders.

I've been googling and i haven't found a solution yet.

Thank you all :D

Comment: it's possible but makes no sense. It's HTML/JS so you can include any script just with `<script src=""` />

Comment: I would build a backend with database, to either store a function or a component itself, that you can then build and save on the database. Then for each user I would fetch the script/component and execute it.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I managed to dynamically include a script tag and attach it to the body, but I always get stuck at the same point. I am unable to render the component.